# Custom Field no Woocommerce não retorna o resultado

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estou tendo um problema com o WooCommerce. Adicionei um campo que não tem no padrão do WooCommerce que seria para adicionar a quantidade de produtos que vão dentro da caixa master do produto.

O código que estou utilizando no meu function.php é o seguinte:

```
    <?php
    //ADICIONANDO UM NOVO CAMPO NA AREA DE EDICAO DO PRODUTO
    /// Display Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

    // Save Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

    /**Fields Container
    **/
    function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

        global $woocommerce, $post;

        echo '<div class="options_group">';

        // Textarea
        woocommerce_wp_text_input(
            array(
                'id' => '_embalageminput',
                'label' => __( 'Embalagem', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'description' => __( 'Quantidade de Peças por Caixa.', 'woocommerce' )
            )
        );

        // END Textarea

        echo '</div>';

    }

    function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save(){
        // Textarea
        $woocommerce_embalagem = $_POST['_embalageminput'];
        if( !empty( $woocommerce_embalagem ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, ‘_embalageminput’, esc_attr( $woocommerce_embalagem) );

        echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_embalageminput', true );
    }

    ?>
```

Quando eu atualizo o produto e volto nele não tem o campo com o valor exibido.
Alguém sabe no que posso estar errando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois problemas com `woo_add_custom_general_fields_save()`.

O primeiro com `‘_embalageminput’`, não existe `‘`, deve ser `'` ou `"`.
Já o segundo é que não existe a variável `$post_id`, então não sabe onde salvar.

O correto é desta forma:

```php
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['_embalageminput'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_embalageminput', esc_attr( $_POST['_embalageminput'] ) );
    }
}
```

O action `woocommerce_process_product_meta` passa o `$post_id` para você, então basta receber ele pela função como eu fiz.